# How do I create a Rust macro to define a String variable with the value of its own identifier?

Tags: macros, rust

I want to write a macro to define something like below:

```
let FOO: String = "FOO".to_string();
```

It is possible for me to have a macro:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($name: ident, $val: expr) => {
        let $name: String = $val.to_string();
    }
}
```

and use it as `my_macro!(FOO, "FOO");`

However, this is a bit redundant. I expect to have something like `my_macro!(FOO)`, and it can expand and use the `$name` as identifier, but also in the string value.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want [`stringify!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html):

```
macro_rules! str_var {
    ($name:ident) => {
        let $name = String::from(stringify!($name));
    };
}

fn main() {
    str_var!(foo);
    println!("foo: {:?}", foo);
}
```

Comment: It's just too bad you can't seem to use `stringify` in attributes.